# AgGrid rowData not updating inside "subscribe" call on Observable object

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, ag-grid

I'm fairly certain this has something to do with a scope issue, but I cannot find anything online about it. I have a service that returns a basic Observable from an API that contains data I want to update my rowData variable with.

MyService.ts

```
 fetchDummyData(): Observable<DummyResponse[]> {
    return this.http.get<DummyResponse[]>('***SOME_API***');
 }
```

MyComponent

If I try to add data to rowData here, the grid is not updated

```
rowData = [];
/////////////
////////////Other stuff

this.myService.fetchDummyData().subscribe(
  data => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      this.rowData.push(
        {
          idType: 'ID Type ' + (i + 1),
          description: 'adfasdf'
        }
      )
      //This log prints the correct thing, but rowData remains empty outside the loop
      console.log('Row id: ' + this.rowData[i].idType);
    }
  }
)
```

But if I add this after the subscribe call above, it works.

```
rowData = [];
/////////////
////////////Other stuff

this.myService.fetchDummyData().subscribe(
  data => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        //Do Nothing
    }
  }
)

//This actually updates the rowData
this.rowData.push(
    {
      idType: 'ID Type ' + (i + 1),
      description: 'adfasdf'
    }
  )
```

Why doesn't rowData update globally inside the subscribe call?

Comment: welcome to [so], reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily. also go through how to create [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular: AgGrid will not update rows when subscribing to Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51830184/angular-aggrid-will-not-update-rows-when-subscribing-to-observable)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `api.setRowData(newData)` inside the subscriber.

```
this.myService.fetchDummyData().subscribe(
    data => {
    let rows = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        rows.push({
            idType: 'ID Type ' + (i + 1),
            description: 'adfasdf'
        });
    }
    this.gridApi.setRowData(rows);
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside a subscription, you should call `markForCheck` change detection.

```
constructor(
 private cd: ChangeDetectorRef
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.fetchDummyData().subscribe(
    data => {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        this.rowData.push(
          {
            idType: 'ID Type ' + (i + 1),
            description: 'adfasdf'
          }
        )
        this.cd.markForCheck()  // Add this code.
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Otherwise, you need to store the API of the grid and explicitly call `gridApi.setRowData(this.rowData)`.