# Angular: AgGrid will not update rows when subscribing to Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, ag-grid

I am trying to incorporate rxjs and observables into ag grid. For practice, I am following an official ag grid example: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-rxjs/

I am currently using Angular 6. I changed the js file to be a ts file and made the appropriate changes. I also do not include any scripts in my index file. I was getting a bunch of MIME errors anytime I called a script. So I converted to code to strictly angular. I believe this is what is causing my issue.
**My goal is to have random rows change their values without having to refresh the web page when I subscribe to my updates observable**

In the code below you will see there is basically an interval function that chooses random numbers to be displayed. When I run my code, All the data is loaded into my grid, but it does not refresh or update. I subscribe to the updates$ observable to output the updated data, but nothing happens. Here is the code. The **onGridReady** function is subscribing to the observable.

Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Model} from '../app/model';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {MockServer} from '../app/mockServer'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: 
    `<ag-grid-angular
    #agGrid
    style="width: 1000px; height: 1500px;"
    id="myGrid"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [enableRangeSelection]="true"
    [enableColResize]="true"
    [deltaRowDataMode]="true"
    [getRowNodeId]="getRowNodeId"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
` ,
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  private gridApi;
  private gridColumnApi;
  private rowData: any[];

  private columnDefs;
  private getRowNodeId;

    constructor() {
      this.columnDefs = [
        {
          headerName: "Code",
          field: "code",
          width: 70
        },
        {
          headerName: "Name",
          field: "name",
          width: 300
        },
        {
          headerName: "Bid",
          field: "bid",
          width: 100,
          cellClass: "cell-number",
          valueFormatter: numberFormatter,
          cellRenderer: "agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer"
        },
        {
          headerName: "Mid",
          field: "mid",
          width: 100,
          cellClass: "cell-number",
          valueFormatter: numberFormatter,
          cellRenderer: "agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer"
        },
        {
          headerName: "Ask",
          field: "ask",
          width: 100,
          cellClass: "cell-number",
          valueFormatter: numberFormatter,
          cellRenderer: "agAnimateShowChangeCellRenderer"
        },
        {
          headerName: "Volume",
          field: "volume",
          width: 80,
          cellClass: "cell-number",
          cellRenderer: "agAnimateSlideCellRenderer"
        }
      ];
      this.getRowNodeId = data => data.code;
    }

ngOnInit() {

}

onGridReady(params) {
  this.gridApi = params.api;
  this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

  
  let mockServer = new MockServer();
  const initialLoad$ = mockServer.initialLoad();
  const updates$ = mockServer.allDataUpdates();
  initialLoad$.subscribe(rowData => {
    params.api.setRowData(rowData);
    updates$.subscribe(newRowData => params.api.setRowData(newRowData));

  });

}
 
}

function numberFormatter(params) {
  if (typeof params.value === "number") {
    return params.value.toFixed(2);
  } else {
    return params.value;
  }
}
```

Here is the server class. This contains the functions that manipulate the data. For brevity, I am only including the methods that are not working correctly. **byRowupdates is what is not working properly**

```
byRowupdates() {
        return Observable.create((observer) => {
            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                let changes = [];
                // make some mock changes to the data
                this.makeSomePriceChanges(changes);
                this.makeSomeVolumeChanges(changes);
               // observer.next(changes);
            }, 1000);
            return () => clearInterval(interval);
        });
    }
    // provides randomised data updates to some of the rows
    // only all the row data (with some rows changed)
    allDataUpdates() {
        return Observable.create((observer) => {
            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                let changes = [];
                // make some mock changes to the data
                this.makeSomePriceChanges(changes);
                this.makeSomeVolumeChanges(changes);
                // this time we don't care about the delta changes only
                // this time we return the full data set which has changed rows within it
                //observer.next(_.cloneDeep(this.rowData));
            }, 1000);

            return () => clearInterval(interval);
            
        });
    }
    /*
     * The rest of the code exists to create or modify mock data
     * it is not important to understand the rest of the example (i.e. the rxjs part of it)
     */
    backfillData(rowData) {
        // the sample data has just name and code, we need to add in dummy figures
        rowData.forEach((dataItem) => {
            // have volume a random between 100 and 10,000
            dataItem.volume = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 100);
            // have mid random from 20 to 300
            dataItem.mid = (Math.random() * 300) + 20;
            this.setBidAndAsk(dataItem);
        });
        return rowData;
    }
    makeSomeVolumeChanges(changes) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // pick a data item at random
            const index = Math.floor(this.rowData.length * Math.random());
            const currentRowData = this.rowData[index];
            // change by a value between -5 and 5
            const move = (Math.floor(10 * Math.random())) - 5;
            const newValue = currentRowData.volume + move;
            currentRowData.volume = newValue;
            changes.push(currentRowData);
        }
    }
    makeSomePriceChanges(changes) {
        // randomly update data for some rows
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            const index = Math.floor(this.rowData.length * Math.random());
            const currentRowData = this.rowData[index];
            // change by a value between -1 and 2 with one decimal place
            const move = (Math.floor(30 * Math.random())) / 10 - 1;
            const newValue = currentRowData.mid + move;
            currentRowData.mid = newValue;
            this.setBidAndAsk(currentRowData);
            changes.push(currentRowData);
        }
    }
    setBidAndAsk(dataItem) {
        dataItem.bid = dataItem.mid * 0.98;
        dataItem.ask = dataItem.mid * 1.02;
    }
}
```

My grid is successfully retrieving the data when it is created, but the grid is not updating new values. I do not have any scripts in my index file. These two classes are doing all the work. I am very confused on how to implement this example properly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting data-binding for grid-data, but it doesn't work like that.
For updating existing data you need to call

```
rowNode.setData(data)
```

> Replaces the data on the rowNode. When complete, the grid will refresh the the entire rendered row if it is showing.

or

```
rowNode.setDataValue(colKey, value)
```

> Replaces the data on the rowNode for the specified column. When complete, the grid will refresh the rendered cell on the required row only.

[Check doc for more details](http://Replaces%20the%20data%20on%20the%20rowNode%20for%20the%20specified%20column.%20When%20complete,%20the%20grid%20will%20refresh%20the%20rendered%20cell%20on%20the%20required%20row%20only.)

*JFI changes through data-binding possible but you would require to make it via `node` and manipulate with `node.data` but I'm not recommending using this type of data-update.

Comment: In my test `rowNode.setData(data)` updated `rowNode.data`, but did not update `gridOptions.rowData` and made the in-consistency.