# angular ag-grid editable cell issue

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am having problems while updating a cell in ag-grid in my angular 8 application. Please find the code below:

```
this.columns = [
    { headerName: '', field: 'enabled', width: 30, headerCheckboxSelection: true, checkboxSelection: true },
    { headerName: 'First Name', field: 'firstName', width: 100 },
    { headerName: 'Address', field: 'address', editable: true, width: 100 },
    { headerName: 'Address1', field: 'address1', editable: true, width: 70 }
];

this.rows = [
    {"first name1", "address", "address1"},
    {"first name2", "address", "address1"}
];
```

The above code allows me to update address and address1 fields, but when I try to get row data it is using the old values. Please find my code below to get data:

```
this.agGrid.api.forEachNode((node) => {
    console.log('-- the node data --', node.data);
});
```

What changes do I need to implement to get updated data from the ag-grid.

Thanks

Comment: have u handled `getRowNodeId` `cellEditingStopped` events? share your entire code OR reproduce your issue on plunk.

Comment: no, I haven't handled the above methods. The above code is all what I have now. Could you please share your's on plunk.

Comment: As far as I tried, it is updating for me when I iterate using `forEachNode()` method. Share your component files (both TS and HTML) in which ag-grid table is displayed. If possible create a minimal reproducible app in Stackblitz.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular: AgGrid will not update rows when subscribing to Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51830184/angular-aggrid-will-not-update-rows-when-subscribing-to-observable)

Answer (score 0):

You can access your data via your `rows` variable.

E.g.:

```
this.rows.forEach((row) => {
    console.log('-- row data --', row);
});
```

Please have a look at the [ag-grid Update](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/) docs.